# Retrieving Numerical Data from MySQL Database using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Good evening. I am creating a game using CANVAS, PHP, MySQL and AJAX. It is a very simple game: it consists of a board, 8 squares tall and 8 squares long (like that of a Chessboard). The user is supposed to click any of the squares, and the square he/she clicked is to be stored in a DataBase as (xpos, ypos). Of course, the DataBase is stored in the server-side and the html game is running on the client-side, so I need AJAX to interact between javascript and php. I did this job and everything worked fine.

My problem arises when I try to load the Board. Imagine we have in our DataBase the next data:

(Row) ... (xpos) ... (ypos)

1         1           2

2         3           2

3         6           5

When the user opens the Game, I need it to Load this positions onto the Board by retrieving the (xpos, ypos) data from the DataBase. The code I tried looks like this:

**Game.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Basic Game</title></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);
function eventWindowLoaded () {
    requestXMLLoadGems();
}
function requestXMLLoadGems() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) { // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { 
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","download_gems.php", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 &&  xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        mycoords=xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.write(mycoords);
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

</script>
<body></body>
</html>
```

The server-side file "download_gems" looks like this:

**download_gems.php**

```
<?php
// Open a MySQL connection
$dbinfo = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$link = new PDO($dbinfo, $user, $pass) or die('Error connecting database');

// Create and execute a MySQL query
$sql = "SELECT xpos,ypos FROM board";

foreach($link->query($sql) as $row) {
    $entries[]=array($row['xpos'], $row['ypos']);
}

print_r($entries);
?>
```

Everything works fine. Except that I need to retrieve Numerical Data (xpos, ypos), and not String data. **My question is how can I retrieve NUMERICAL Data using**:

```
xmlhttp.responseText;
```

I can't find the answer anywhere!

I would appreciate any help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of print_r(), use json_encode() and send the output with a JSON content type header. Then use a JSON parser on the client side. E.g. jQuery auto-converts valid JSON to a JavaScript object for you if you use it's ajax functionality.

Unrelated: you will not be able (nor would you want) to use document.write(), for this (or just about anything!).

Comment: Hello Steve. From your response I guess I need to learn JSON and jQuery, and that's what I am working on now. May you be a little bit more explicit about your proposed solution to my problem? I would appreciate it so much.

Comment: I got it! I added these lines to **download_gems.php**:

    $x = json_encode($entries);  
    echo $x;

And this line to **Game.html**

    var objMisCoords = JSON.parse(miscoords);

Now, I have the coords in the object "objMisCoords", ready to be used. Thanks a lot Steve !!